# finding the least frequent number using two for loops?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

**I am trying to find the least frequent element of an array, I tried to sort the array by using insertion sort and then used two loops; the outer loop for picking each element and inner loop for comparison.**

```
# include <stdio.h>
void LeastFrequentnum(int arr[],int n);
void InsertionSort(int arr[],int n);

    int main()
    {
        int arr[] = {1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1};
        int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
        LeastFrequentnum(arr,n);
    }

    void LeastFrequentnum(int arr[],int n)
    {
        InsertionSort(arr,n);
        int count = 1;
        int min_count = n+1;// i will update min_count
        int res=-1; // used to store the element which occurs least number of times
        for(int i=0;i<n;)
        {
            count=1;
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(arr[j]==arr[i])
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = j+1;
                    if(count<min_count)
                    {
                       min_count = count;
                       res = arr[j];
                       break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        printf("%d",res);
    }

    void InsertionSort(int arr[],int n)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            int key = arr[i];
            int j = i-1;
            while(j>=0 && arr[j]>key)
            {
                arr[j+1] = arr[j];
                j--;
            }
            arr[j+1]=key;
        }
    }
```

**I tried running it, but the run time result is a time limit exceeded issue.**

Comment: is it ok to use a lot of memory? inneficient method?

Comment: cAN YOU ALSO GIVE CONSTRAINTS? MAX NUMBER? MIN NUMBER? ARRAY LENGTH?

Comment: yes sir, i want to know what went wrong in this code.

Comment: So you want to take more space or more time? Also what is the range of these numbers? Is it necesary to use more than one for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is an endless loop. Try this.

```
# include <stdio.h>
void LeastFrequentnum(int arr[],int n);
void InsertionSort(int arr[],int n);

    int main()
    {
        int arr[] = {1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1};
        int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
        LeastFrequentnum(arr,n);
    }

    void LeastFrequentnum(int arr[],int n)
    {
        InsertionSort(arr,n);
        int count = 1;
        int min_count = n+1;// i will update min_count
        int res=-1; // used to store the element which occurs least number of times
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            count=1;
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(arr[j]==arr[i])
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = j+1;
                    if(count<min_count)
                    {
                       min_count = count;
                       res = arr[j];
                       break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        printf("%d",res);
    }

    void InsertionSort(int arr[],int n)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            int key = arr[i];
            int j = i-1;
            while(j>=0 && arr[j]>key)
            {
                arr[j+1] = arr[j];
                j--;
            }
            arr[j+1]=key;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its this part of the code --> `for(int i=0;i<n;)`

I think you are missing the i++